# random script don't run

Tags: php, random

php random script running slowly

here seems to be the problem

```
<?php   
   function sortear($prevItems, $number) {
     for ($k=0; $k<sizeof($prevItems); $k++) {
       if ($prevItems[$k] == $number)
          return true;
     }
       return false;
   }
   for ($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) {       
      $num[$i] = rand($_GET['inicial'],$_GET['final']);      
      while (sortear($prevItems, $num[$i])) {          
         $num[$i] = rand($_GET['inicial'],$_GET['final']);       
      }       
    $prevItems[$i] = $num[$i];
    }

   sort($num);

?>
```

any sugestion for this random?
rest of code here

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/sn5t3bo7/)

Comment: What does this have to do with random?

Comment: what does do this code?

Comment: Why would you put PHP in jsfiddle? Use ideone.com for PHP demonstrations.

Comment: what is the point of `sortear()`? what are you trying to accomplish there that `in_array()` couldn't do for you already?

Comment: FYI, `$prevItems` is initially undefined in your `for` loop.

Comment: Rest of code is in link. Well, you're right. Coz usually use jsfiddle :) sorry

Comment: What range of variables are you passing into GET?

Comment: sortear pick the values of input boxs and create a 10 randon numbers

Comment: David, please tell me what you mean about prev items thanks

Comment: range? do  you mean something like random (10,100)?

Comment: Use count and not sizeof. Also use foreach and not for loops. It s easier to extract keyes and values....

Comment: Thanks cpugouru! I will take your advices in account to a better coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an infinite loop; the `while` loop was never terminating because you were never increasing the size of the `$prevItems` array.

Try this:

```
function sortear($prevItems, $number) {
    for ($k=0; $k<sizeof($prevItems); $k++) {
        if ($prevItems[$k] == $number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

for ($i=0; $i<=9; $i++) {       
    $num[$i] = rand($_GET['inicial'],$_GET['final']);      
    while (sortear($prevItems, $num[$i])) {          
        $num[$i] = rand($_GET['inicial'],$_GET['final']); 
        $prevItems[$i] = $num[$i];      
    }       
}

sort($num);
```

Granted, I have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish. All I know is that your script is broken because the while loop just keeps going and going...

### **EDIT:**

If you're just trying to create a randomized array that contains all the values between a *start* number and an *end* number, do this:

```
$initial = $_GET['inicial'];
$final = $_GET['final'];

for ($i=$initial; $i<=$final; $i++) {
    $num[] = $i;
}

shuffle($num);
```

Comment: thanks david 

now it stops the loop but 
aparently script isn't generating the values with this code

Comment: what exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: sorry, its running
but is repeating values 
any idea to solve that?

(where can I share php scripts to show you?)

Comment: You can edit your initial question if you have more information to share. It's helpful to know 1) what you're putting into your function, and b) what you expect out from it

Comment: I edited my response. Still not quite sure I'm understanding you, but I'm trying!

Comment: That's it! Sorry for my bad explanation. 
That's it. Thank you very much David!

Comment: @Anibal You're welcome! Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if it helped you